# How to select rows that differ only in some condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Can I somehow select only rows with same id, where difference between values not more than 10?

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE_TEST (ID NUMBER, VALUE NUMBER);
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_TEST(ID, VALUE) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_TEST(ID, VALUE) VALUES (2, 4);
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_TEST(ID, VALUE) VALUES (1, 9);
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_TEST(ID, VALUE) VALUES (2, 15);
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_TEST(ID, VALUE) VALUES (1, 17);
```

The only thing I came up with is to join the same table, but it is obviously wrong approach as you don't know how many rows there'll be.

May be PLSQL is the key here? But I couldn't come up with it either.

Comment: So in this example you want to select only the two rows for ID 2 (which have a distance of 11) and no row for ID 1, because each ID 1 record has another record with too close a value?

Comment: Actually, it is vice versa, @Thorsten. He said "not more than 10". Though, if the last row's value was 30, what then? ID = 1 for three rows. Their values are 1, 9 and 30. Should ID = 1 be displayed (because 9 - 1 = 8 which is less than 10) or not (because 30 - 1 = 29, or 30 - 9 = 21, which is more than 10)?

Comment: Exact the opposite. I need to select only rows with ID = 1 because difference betweeen their values is < 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to select each record for which **exists** a close-value record. So use `EXISTS`:

```
select *
from example_test
where exists
(
  select *
  from example_test other
  where other.id = example_test.id
  and other.value <> example_test.value
  and abs(other.value - example_test.value) <= 10
)
order by id, value;
```

Comment: But it returns rows with id=2 as well

Comment: Oops, that was because I compared each record also with itself. I've added the missing clause. In case of duplicate records (same ID, same value), you'd have to decide whether you want to show them or not, though. (This can lead to what lad2025 had in mind with identifying a record uniquely.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Example_test e1
JOIN Example_test e2
  ON e1.ID = e2.id
 AND ABS(e1.value-e2.value) < 10
 AND e1.value ^= e2.value;
 -- to get nice triangular join you need some kind of unique column
 -- (identity/sequence/timestamp)
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=75a56d101caebb8dea7d7c106a03c5cc)**

EDIT:

> That looks pretty impressive. But why do I need a unique column? Will rowid work?

Good point

```
SELECT *
FROM Example_test e1
JOIN Example_test e2
  ON e1.ID = e2.id
 AND ABS(e1.value-e2.value) < 10
 AND e1.rowid > e2.rowid;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b97364a71163fc3eb11d1454db5e7a59)**

Comment: That looks pretty impressive. But why do I need a unique column? Will rowid work? If I understand this right, it will result in getting three rows (what I need), but not four as I recieve now?

Comment: Thanks, but now it's two rows. Probably becuse of two tables in join (I may be not quite on point here).

Comment: @Bobby Nope, triangular join is for avoiding "duplicates" (A,B) and (B,A) are basically the same.

Comment: Oh, now I got it, thank you. But the expected result I need is id=1 and values 1, 9 and 17

Comment: @Bobby So you got it: 1-9/9-17

Comment: It's a bad idea to join when you are not interested in the joined result. With values 1, 2, 3, and 4 you'd already get six records with your method. You can `SELECT DISTINCT e1.*`, but I would not recommend this. Why build up an unnecessarily big intermediate result, only to fight to reduce it later?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner At the begining the questin was a bit vague. This approach show which pairs are within 10 unit distance (your approach does not show that at all 1 and 17). Anyway it is up to OP what he really needs.